# how we can shift X and Y axis to center in Bubble chart (JQPlot)

Tags: jquery, css, jqplot

I am trying to shift bubble chart X and Y axis to the center. I am unable to find the exact configuration.

Currently i am getting the graph as shown below

[image]

I want to get it as shown below

[image]

please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any [api options](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis) to change the position the axis.  So, the best I can come up with is to set it using CSS.

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1',[arr],{
    title: 'Transparent Bubbles',
    seriesDefaults:{
        renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
        rendererOptions: {
            bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
            highlightAlpha: 0.8
        },
        shadow: true,
        shadowAlpha: 0.05
    },
    axes:{yaxis:{tickOptions: {showMark:false},min:-500,max:500}, //disable the ticks
          xaxis:{tickOptions: {showMark:false},min:-500,max:500}}
}); 

$('.jqplot-xaxis').css({'zIndex':10,'top':'150px','font-weight':'bold'}); // move the axis to the center of the chart
$('.jqplot-yaxis').css({'zIndex':10,'left':'300px','font-weight':'bold'});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RATwU/).

Produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

find the center number, double click the y axis.  Under Axis Options, under Horizontal axis crosses: Chose Axis Value: and enter the halfway point where you want it to be.  For instance on a y axis that has 0 - 5, you would enter 2.5.

do the same with your x axis.

Hope that helps! :)